# PHP Nested escapeshellarg()

Tags: php, shell, escaping, exec

I am using PHP to generate a shell command that I then pass to PHP's `exec()` function. I am extensively using `escapeshellarg()` to make sure there aren't any security issues and also to ensure that certain Linux shell attributes and operators are being applied in the right spots (like stream redirects).

So here is a general example of my problem:

I am nesting `escapeshellarg()` three times, like this:

```
echo "first_program -f " . escapeshellarg("second_program -f ". escapeshellarg("third_program -f " . escapeshellarg("value")));
```

The output of this is:

```
first_program -f 'second_program -f '\''third_program -f '\''\'\'''\''value'\''\'\'''\'''\'''
```

As you can see, once it gets to the third `escapeshellarg()` function call, it starts going crazy with escaping characters.

When this gets executed by the `exec()` function, it doesn't *un-escape* it correctly and therefore doesn't execute correctly.

Am I missing something? Or does the `escapeshellarg()` function break if you nest it like this? It works only nesting it twice, but then on the third nesting it goes crazy. Should I be using `escapeshellcmd()` in some places? I'm passing all of these in as arguments so I don't see why I wouldn't use the `escapeshellarg()`.